# What is the set type for ACTION_SENDTO

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext, whatsapp

I am trying to send message on *WhatsApp* by setting the contact. The *WhatsApp* profile of the contact is shown, but the content of the EditText is not set to the *WhatsApp* profile.

My code is:

```
            String id =etxnumber.getText().toString();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + id);
            String text1 =etxmsg.getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
            i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text1);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(i);
```

Error is:

`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO typ=text/plain pkg=com.whatsapp (has extras) }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code

```
String id =etxnumber.getText().toString();
                String text1 =etxmsg.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                  Uri.parse(
                       "content://com.android.contacts/data/" +           
                        id));
                i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text1);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(i);
```